# Still getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, cross-domain

I have a web application on asp.net that uses Jquery-ajax call to **GET** some data from a restful service. This WCF service working proper that I can call it in my browser with it's '*UriTemplate*' , next my data will be shown.

But, When I using ajax call to get the content, **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** Error will be logged. Consider that I've been set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Header parameters in my web.config file, but didn't get the result.

Error Content:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/MonitorDataProviderService/MonitorData. Origin http://localhost:2265 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My **ajax call** is in a ascx script block:

```
function FillDataA()
{
    console.log("Address is : " + address);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: address,//Address is valid
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert("WIN");
        },
        error: function (msg) { console.log("ERROR"); }
    });
    setTimeout(function () { FillDataA(); }, 2000);//The method is calling continuously 
}
```

**Config** file tags:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:2265" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Also, Adding it on **Global.asax** wasn't helpful:

```
     protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                          "*"); 
// I've Tested fixed url in place of '*' too

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 
                              "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                              "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age",
                              "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

**Browsers** Used:
 - Chrome 28
 - Firefox 22.0

Any Helpful idea will be appreciated

Best Regards

Comment: did u read about JSONP.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about.it may solve your problem

Comment: Just right now, I read the article... What does make sense? Where should I change my code to get JSONP? Can you prepare some code, please?

Comment: What is the language used to write the AJAX response? The header response changes need to go in that server part and not in the ASP website. (assuming you aren't using ASP to serve the AJAX response)

Comment: can you remove the custom header code from web config. it may works